# Persisting Form Data using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to figure out how to persist user input from a form using SpringMVC and hibernate. for an example, I'm following this guide:

[spring.io guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

basically it shows a controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    return "greeting";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
    return "result";
}
}
```

a Greeting.java where I added some annotations for JPA, but I'm not sure if the form gets its own object and i need to create a separate object for the greeting entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "greeting")
public class Greeting {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "greeting_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "greeting_content")
private String content;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
}
```

as well as the html for display and the pom which has only the starter-web and thyme leaf dependencies...

I also created a simple repository which extends the CrudRepository, as well as a service layer which is empty at the moment.

what i am trying to figure out is how to use hibernate to persist the greeting field to a database when the submit button is clicked. any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: CrudRepository has a save() method. That's what it's for. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-

Comment: @JBNizet This might be me just being slow, but when/ where does that get called, in the POST method?

Comment: Well, you need to call it, that's the point. Inject the service in your controller, inject the repository in the service, call a save() method of the service from the controller, call the save() method of the repository from the service. Things only happen if you code them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring `CrudRepository` provides the `save()` method. A simple way to test your code and your Spring/Entity configuration you can try like this:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

 //Autowire your CrudRepo of Greeting
   @Autowired
   GreetingRepository repository;

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    //create a new Greeting() Object and set your values to it.
    //create a constructor if the values are not that much.
    Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
    greeting.setContent(yourContent);
    repository.save(greeting);
    return "greeting";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
    //create a new Greeting() Object and set your values to it.
    //create a constructor if the values are not that much.
    Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
    greeting.setContent(yourContent);
    repository.save(greeting);
    return "result";
}
}
```

And the CrudRepository interface should look like this in default:

```
@Repository
public interface GreetingRepository extends CrudRepository<Greeting, Serializable>{

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide me the full code. I'm confused what should be in "yourContent" in the post method

Comment: @Vigneshcs "yourContent" is any content which this particular object needs. Its just an attribute of the object.